# Curve handles aren't working

Tags: bezier-curves

I know I must have toggled something but for the life of me I can't figure it out. In this one Blender file any time I make a curve and go into Edit mode I cannot adjust the handles of the curve. The handles are there but whatever point I click on(be it vertex or handle) and try to move it, the whole curve moves. However if I open up a different or new project the curve handles work just fine and I can change the shape of the curve with ease. I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. If someone could help be I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Did you mean to mark this as a duplicate of a duplicate question of a duplicate question?

Comment: Haha no I did not. It was just the first that came up on my search, though it does seem like an appropriate coincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have proportional editing turned on?  Toggle this on/off to see if your proportional editing zone is simply not visible and gives the impression the entire curve is moving as you try to adjust.

Comment: Hee hee I can't tell you how many times that one has driven me crazy!  Cheers!